# Remove whole group if value of grouped item is zero

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object

```
public class ActiveUser
{
  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}
```

with data

```
List<ActiveUser> userList = new List<ActiveUser>();
userList.Add( new User { UserID = 1, UserName = "UserOne", Location = "LOne", IsActive= false } );
userList.Add( new User { UserID = 1, UserName = "UserOne", Location = "LTwo", IsActive= false } );
userList.Add( new User { UserID = 2, UserName = "UserTwo", Location = "LOne", IsActive= true } );
userList.Add( new User { UserID = 2, UserName = "UserTwo", Location = "LTwo", IsActive= false } );
userList.Add( new User { UserID = 2, UserName = "UserTwo", Location = "LThree", IsActive= true } );
userList.Add( new User { UserID = , UserName = "UserThree", Location = "LOne", IsActive= true } );
```

What I Want?
I want to select data with the following condition using LinQ or lambda expressions using C#.

- If we group by UserID, in that group, if IsActive is false for all the row, then that group need not be selected.
- If the group contains at least one IsActive as True, then we have to select all the rows in the group including IsActive = false

So the output should be like all rows with UserID = 1 get removed and all other rows get included.

I tried something like this and i'm stuck. I dont have any idea how to use this.

```
userList.GroupBy(c => c.UserID).Select(g => g.UserName )
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to alter the original list, then a `for` loop is more appropriate.  If you want to create a *new* list with just the items that have at least one active item, then you can add a `Where` after the `GroupBy`:

```
var query = userList.GroupBy(c => c.UserID)
                    .Where(g => g.Any(c => c.IsActive))
```

note that you can't do `Select(g => g.UserName)` because the output of a `GroupBy` is a collection of *groups*, and the groups do not expose the properties of the items within them. If you want to project the original items instead of groups, use `SelectMany` to "flatten" the groups:

```
var query = userList.GroupBy(c => c.UserID)
                    .Where(g => g.Any(c => c.IsActive))
                    .SelectMany(g => g)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group.Any(u => u.IsActive)`

```
var allWithAtLeastOneActiveUser = userList
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.UserID, c.UserName })
    .Where(g => g.Any(u => u.IsActive));
```

If you want to flatten these groups:

```
List<ActiveUser> allWithAtLeastOneActiveUser  = userList
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.UserID, c.UserName })
    .Where(g => g.Any(u => u.IsActive))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```